# Login to Windows 10 through OpenSSH Server As Regular User gives Administrator Privileges

Tags: windows, ssh, permissions, command-line-interface, access-control-list

I have installed OpenSSH server on a Windows 10 system and added my public key to the file at  `C:\Users\foo\.ssh\authorized_keys`.

However, when I log in to the Windows account using SSH and created a new directory, the owner is `BUILTIN\Administrators` and not the user I am connecting as!

```
$ ssh foo@win10host

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1339]                                                                                                                   
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                              
foo@WIN10HOST C:\Users\foo>mkdir test                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                              
foo@WIN10HOST C:\Users\foo>dir /q                                                                                                                                  
 Volume in drive C has no label.                                                                                                                              
 Volume Serial Number is 6334-07A6                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                              
 Directory of C:\Users\foo

07/21/2020  11:03 AM    <DIR>          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    .                                                                                               
07/21/2020  11:03 AM    <DIR>          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    ..                                                                                           
06/03/2020  01:05 PM    <DIR>          WIN10HOST\foo               .ssh                                                                                             
07/15/2020  07:22 AM    <DIR>          WIN10HOST\foo               3D Objects                                                                                      
07/15/2020  07:22 AM    <DIR>          WIN10HOST\foo               Contacts                                                                                        
07/21/2020  10:38 AM    <DIR>          WIN10HOST\foo               Desktop                                                                                         
07/15/2020  07:22 AM    <DIR>          WIN10HOST\foo               Documents                                                                                       
07/15/2020  07:22 AM    <DIR>          WIN10HOST\foo               Downloads                                                                                       
07/15/2020  07:22 AM    <DIR>          WIN10HOST\foo               Favorites                                                                                       
07/15/2020  07:22 AM    <DIR>          WIN10HOST\foo               Links                                                                                           
07/15/2020  07:22 AM    <DIR>          WIN10HOST\foo               Music                                                                                           
07/15/2020  07:22 AM    <DIR>          WIN10HOST\foo               Pictures                                                                                  
07/15/2020  07:22 AM    <DIR>          WIN10HOST\foo               Saved Games                                                                                     
07/15/2020  07:22 AM    <DIR>          WIN10HOST\foo               Searches                                                                                        
07/21/2020  11:03 AM    <DIR>          BUILTIN\Administrators      test
```

`whoami` shows that I am the user `foo` during the SSH session...

```
foo@WIN10HOST C:\Users\foo>whoami                                                                                                                                  
win10host\foo
```

Why was the `test` directory created as `BUILTIN\Administrators` instead of `WIN10HOST\foo`? How can we configure OpenSSH to allow me to log in and run programs as the user `foo`?

Thanks!

---

In the SSHD config file at `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config`, the following lines are commented out

```
#Match Group administrators
#       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```